# WPF DataGrid ScrollBar reset when DataContext Changed

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, scrollbar, datacontext

Is there any alternative way to reset the scrollbar of a DataGrid when its DataContext changed except using DataContext_changed event?

Thanks for help..

Cheers,

Sravanthi Chepooru

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The event is there for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Can you please explain why the Changed event is not suitable?

Comment: I have using this DataGrid for displaying search result..I have totally 200 forms containing search..this may not possible for me to apply changed event for all the forms..Is there a way to apply it in theme?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a sub class of DataGrid and implement your event handler in there.